# Postgresql is not running. It's active but exited

Tags: linux, postgresql, systemd

Postgresql is not running.

Versions

```
PostgreSQL Version: 10.12
Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 (Tricia)/Ubuntu 18.04
```

Not working:

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

systemctl status postgresql:

```
╭─root@danial /opt
╰─➤  systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2020-07-13 22:52:54 +03; 9min ago
  Process: 22887 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22887 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 13 22:52:54 17-V13-5 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jul 13 22:52:54 17-V13-5 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

ss -nlp | grep postgre

```
u_str             LISTEN              0                    128                                                   /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 188329                                                 * 0                                    users:(("postgres",pid=22869,fd=8))

tcp               LISTEN              0                    128                                                                           127.0.0.1:5432                                             0.0.0.0:*
```

pg_lsclusters

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

ps ax | grep -i postgresq

```
 1495 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
```

systemctl status postgresql@10.12-main

```
● postgresql@10.12-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10.12-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Wed 2020-07-15 07:20:02 +03; 51s ago
```

Comment: But it is running! Are you actually having a problem with it?

Comment: Which one is norma l"Active: active (exited)"  Or  "Active: active (running)" ?

Comment: For the status of the 10/main cluster, invoke `systemctl status postgresql@10-main` (not postgresql@10.12-main)

Comment: @DanielVérité thanks a lots for this trick! i got it

Answer (score 4):

The `postgresql.service` systemd unit used as a top level grouping service, that does nothing than starting and sopping other services that depend on it.

As it implemented as **service**, it required to have a dummy **ExecStart**:

```
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=on
```

You can examine that by running

```
systemctl cat postgresql.service
```

However (unfortunately), it's own status says nothing about services that depend on in. It just tells you that `postgresql.service` have been started and depending services requested to start.

Comment: Understood thank you!

Comment: should be `systemctl cat postgresql.service`

Comment: @MyersC Thanks. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @kofeman, the `postgresql.service` is only used to manage the services for the actual installed postgresql clusters.

To see the real status of your database cluster(s) service(s), use

```
systemctl status 'postgresql*'
```

This will list the status for each of your installed clusters.

When restarting (or reloading) postgres, you can use this to get useful feedback:

```
systemctl restart postgresql && systemctl status 'postgresql*'
```